# Pwa venia theme product page slider is not working

Tags: progressive-web-apps, magento-2.3, venia

I am using magento 2.3 venia storefront. I installed it successfully,but in product page its slider is not working properly.The product page thumbnail is not clickable on venia store front

when I click the product thumbnail its main image need to replace with thumbnail image

Comment: Could you share the code you used?

Comment: I am using the default venia theme and magento 2.3